# Suggestions For Improving Page Load Speed

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm about to take a re-design of a website live but have noticed that one of the sites pages, the gallery page loads very slowly.

I've used a sprite image for most of the images on the site for performance, and if I can want to keep the format of the gallery page, that is having multiple galleria galleries on the page.

Can you suggest a way to improve the page loading time?

I thought of having each gallery available on the page with the topmost one fully loaded and using jQuery or jQuery UI to have the others as title only, and a section under the title saying "click to display" like an accordion effect. But wouldn't the page load these anyway and just not display them?

The website URL is www.f3racing.co.uk/staging

I've created a guest log in:

Username: guest

Passowrd: stackoverflow240113

Thanks in advance for any help and/or suggestions.

Comment: Your page loads slowly because you have 80 large images (the one I looked at was 294kb which means users are having to download around 22mb of images) loading

Comment: Yeah I just noticed the options for galleria thumbnails and full screen images separately. Sorry, a slight case of RTFM, answer with RTFM or something similar @Pete and I'll chose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page loads slowly because you have 80 large images loading - the one I looked at was 294kb which means users are having to download around 22mb of images

Comment: Thanks @Pete, I think it's time to make myself some coffee.